# Executing command in background by shell_exec()

Tags: php, windows, shell-exec

On Linux I can use `shell_exec()` as below to run the command in **background**:

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/nohup curl -o /dev/null --data \"$data\" $url >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Note that the above line doesn't wait for the result and the code will resume instantly.

How can I achieve it on windows? It's preferable to be something built-in for windows.

Comment: You can do the same on windows if you just remove the /usr/bin/nohup part. That is not required on windows since processes don't quit when the parent process is killed.

Comment: @Xatenev In my edit I noted I don't want to wait for the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check out the Symfony Process component for this use case. It provides methods for executing synchronously and asynchronously. It can be easily installed through Composer, but it requires PHP 7.1 at least.
The documentation can be found here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

An example for your use case could look like this:

```
$process = new Process(['curl', '--data', $data, $url]);
$process->start();
```

Note that I omitted the `-o` option because the output of the sub process won't show up unless you request it explicitly.
A quick browse yielded some posts that said that the `start()` method blocks on Windows but it seems that a patch has already been implemented and merged: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/10420

**EDIT:** If you don't want to use a library, you can use a combination of `popen()`, `pclose()` and the Windows tool `start`:

```
pclose(popen('start /B curl --data "'.$data.'" '.$url, 'r'));
```

This runs the program in background without opening a window and immediately returns.

**EDIT 2:** Source for the trick with `start /B`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86329

Comment: I prefer something built-in and PHP version 5.6

Comment: Please see my edit. Regarding your PHP version (a little off-topic): PHP 5.6 will be EOL at the end of this year and won't receive any more security updates. So you should look into updating soon. But my edited solution works on 5.6 as well :)

Comment: popen needs a second parameter **mode**. I think either values `'r'` or `'w'` works in this case. and thanks for the heads up. I will consider it.

Comment: Oh yeah, sure. I made the mistake while copying from my test file, sorry. I guess `'r'` would be better to possibly get errors or something from the process in case you need to, but both should work as you said.